# Logo image with text on css3 gradient background of web page

Tags: layout, css, photoshop, web-deployment

In a web page there is a gradient (in body tag) using CSS3. Moving next and adding image (logo with site name) I realized page gradient and image both has different colors. It is because web page has a background generated by CSS3 and image has a fixed color as background and both are different.

**What I have tried ?**
add image as background of a div and also as a img tag.
applying gradient on div

but no luck.

How it can be managed ? Please guide.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Cant you just save the text of your logo as a .png with a transparent background? If you've added the gradient to your body tag it will change when the browser window expands and contracts

Answer (score 0):

you have to save your logo image with transparent background....you open the psd file of the logo and disable the visibility of the background layer and then save it as a png image.